# How to download external files with Wget

Tags: wget

I am trying to mirror a website and include external file pointing to a sharepoint pdf.

Also, does wget automatically download subdomains, for example if i want to download stackexchange.com it will download all xxxx.stackexchange.com?

Comment: `wget` does not download subdomains unless there is a link to the subdomain on the original site and you allow `wget` to follow these links with `--span-hosts`. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16780601/10622916

Answer (score 0):

From wget manpage :

> Wget can follow links in HTML, XHTML, and CSS pages, to create local
> versions of remote web sites, **fully recreating the directory structure
> of the original site**.  This is sometimes referred to as "recursive
> downloading."  While doing that, Wget respects the Robot Exclusion
> Standard (/robots.txt).  Wget can be instructed to convert the links
> in downloaded files to point at the local files, for offline viewing.

From what you can deduce that, if the subdomains are laying their files in subdirectories of the domain or if pages in the domain link to the subdomains, you might expect downloading nearly everything.

*Nearly* since, if the website is correctly maintained, several files should be made not accessible thanks to the robots.txt.

BTW, I would personally prefer asking for permission to proceed and probably take benefits of some sftp access.

Of course you are aware that pages of the website might well be dynamically generated by some server script, use whatever data from some server database. All that sort of things won't be downloaded.

**Since this is nowadays more than likely, you cannot actually expect formally *mirorring* the website that way.**